# SQL query not returning the things I want

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, pivot, aggregate-functions

I am confused about why my query is not returning the things I want.  Can someone please give me a hand on this?

**Tables:**
[image]

**Query(CTE):**

```
WITH cancel AS(
SELECT t.Request_at AS day, IFNULL(COUNT(t.Status),0) AS cancelled
FROM Trips t
LEFT JOIN Users u
ON t.Client_Id = u.Users_Id
WHERE (t.Status = "cancelled_by_driver" or t.Status = "cancelled_by_client")
AND t.Request_at BETWEEN "2013-10-01" AND "2013-10-03"
AND u.Banned = "No"
GROUP BY t.Request_at)
```

So what I want here is to make the cte I have above to return the number of trips that is canceled by the unbanned users or the driver between Oct 1, 2013 and Oct 3, 2013.  My query is returning the correct number for the one that got canceled but it is not returning "0" for the date that has no cancellation.  I can't figure out why the result is like this as I am using IFNULL and along with left join already.

Comment: Please put. your query in the question as text.

Comment: Hi Gordan, I just put them as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `where` clause evicts dates that have no cancelled drive before you get a chance to include them in the resultset.

If you have all dates available in the table (regardless of the status), you can just move the conditions within the aggregate:

```
select t.request_at, 
    sum(t.status in ('cancelled_by_driver', 'cancelled_by_client')) as cnt_cancelled
from trips t
inner join users u on u.user_id = t.client_id
where u.banned = 'No' and t.request_at between '2013-10-01' and '2013-10-03'
group by t.request_at
```

A more generic approach uses a calendar table to handle the dates, then brings the table with a `left join`. If you don't have such table, you can generate it on the fly with a recursive query (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
with recursive cal as (
    select '2013-10-01' as dt
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 day from cal where dt < '2013-10-03'
)
select c.dt, count(t.id) as cnt_cancelled
from cal c
left join trips t on t.request_at = c.dt and t.status in ('cancelled_by_driver', 'cancelled_by_client')
left join users u on u.user_id = t.client_id and u.banned = 'No'
group by c.dt
```

Comment: Hi! So that means my query will run the where part prior to the IFNULL?

Comment: And is that mean I cannot use COUNT here?

Comment: @EricsonLi: the `where` clause *filters* the dataset. in your original query, this eliminates dates that have no cancelled request.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!